# Preloaded image (using service worker) still takes time to load

Tags: service-worker, preload

[image: WHY]

This image has been preloaded with a service worker on the previous page. It's in the cache. Why does it still take time to load?

The relevant service worker line is just:

```
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
    '/1.jpg'
]);
```

It's on https and so on.

WHY?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it can take time to pass a response from the service worker to the main page if the main page is executing a large amount of JavaScript.

If you see this happening during a period of time when the [Profiling in DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/devtools-javascript-cpu-profile-migration) shows that there is a large amount of JavaScript being executed, that could explain it.

You can also mouse over the Waterfall bar chart to get some [more context](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing#viewing_in_devtools) about the breakdown of that 749ms.